# Regex that would grep the time after a string

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

So, I am trying to write a script for my dwmblocks status bar and I'd like to get a small module for checking the Sunset and Sunrise times. Apparently, [this website](https://v2.wttr.in/nyc) can help me do the same but I do not know how to grep out the sunrise and sunset values from the curl file.

```
curl v2.wttr.in/nyc | grep (the values after 'Sunrise:  ' and 'Sunset:  ')
```

Can you make a regex that would return the values without, 'Sunrise:  ' and 'Sunset:  '

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work as expected or intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `grep` has the `-P` and `-o` options.

```
$ curl -s v2.wttr.in/nyc | grep -Po 'Sun(rise|set):.*?\K\d+:\d+:\d+'
07:31:15
17:47:15
```

`.*?` skips as few characters as possible until a `digits:digits:digits` pattern is found. That skips the whitespace but also the colouring escape sequences that are found there. `\K` tells were the part output for `-o` starts (what's to be `K`ept from the match).

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|").map: *.trim; \
          .[2].put if .contains("Sunrise" | "Sunset") for @a.map: *.split( / \s+ /);'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|").map: *.trim; \
          .put for @a.grep(/ Sunrise | Sunset /).map: *.split(/ \s+ / ).[2];'
```

It seems that the page `curl`ed by the OP is a highly-structured document, so take advantage of that property. The code above (both examples) takes lines, splits them on `|` bar into separate columns, and stores the result in an array ( `@a` ).

First example: in the second statement, elements of `@a` are `split` on `\s+` into keys/values. These keys/values iterated through with `for`, and only the `[2]` third (value) sub-element is displayed if it `contains` the `Sunrise` and/or `Sunset` strings.

Second example: elements of `@a` array are `grep`ped through until a match to `Sunrise` or `Sunset` is found. Then any `grep`ped elements are `split` on `\s+` into key/values, and the value ( index `[2]` ) is returned.

---

The Raku answers above have the advantage that you return the values associated with "Sunrise" or "Sunset", whatever they may be. For example, if the site switches to a 12hr clock, you would get `AM/PM` info returned. Alternatively, the excellent answer by @StéphaneChazelas actually selects-out colon-separated digits. Using Raku you could similarly 'go the extra mile' and `comb` through the third  (value) sub-element for the correct digit pattern:

```perl
.comb(/ [\d**2] ** 3 % \: /)
```

The Raku regex in `comb` can be read as follows: *find-and-return matches to `\d**2` pairs of digits, repeated `** 3` three times, internally-separated (`%`) by a `\:` colon*.

Putting it all together:

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|").map: *.trim; \
          .comb(/ [\d**2] ** 3 % \: /).put for @a.grep(/ Sunrise | Sunset /).map: *.split(/ \s+ / ).[2];'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|").map: *.trim; .[2].comb(/ [\d**2] ** 3 % \: /).put if .contains("Sunrise" | "Sunset") for @a.map: *.split( / \s+ /);'
```

Breaking down the text in the structured way above assures you that you're only getting `dd:dd:dd` times associated with either "Sunrise" or "Sunset". Of course, you can feel free to combine/drop recognition elements from all 4 code examples above, as you see fit.

Sample Output (all 4 code examples above):

```
07:31:15
17:47:15
```

https://rakudo.org
https://raku.org